# MongoDB: find records using the date interval calculated from item value

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to achieve the same results as I can get from MySQL query:

`select * from items where updated_at + refresh_interval < now()`

where `updated_at` is a BSON\UTCDateTime and `refresh_interval` is int holding interval in seconds.

for my MongoDB collection. 
So I probably need $add and Date() functions, but I have hard time to understand where exactly these should be used.

Comment: What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: @veeram `db.version() 3.6.2`

Comment: Try `db.items.find({$expr:{$lt:[{$add:["$updated_at", {$multiply:["$refresh_interval", 1000]}, new Date()]}})`

Comment: @chridam, not exactly, but thanks for pointing out for `$expr` operator.
I have to add `$multiply: ["$update_interval", 1000]` since my `refresh_interval` is in seconds.